# MongoDB on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, mongodb

So, I already have a Raspberry Pi running with Raspbian, but I can't seem to install MongoDB. I followed some tutorials ([here](http://c-mobberley.com/wordpress/2013/10/14/raspberry-pi-mongodb-installation-the-working-guide/) and [here](https://emersonveenstra.net/mongodb-raspberry-pi/)) with pre-built mongo installations, but those all failed.

Everywhere I see there is the suggestion that I should use Archlinux, but since my Rpi is already used a lot, I don't have this option.

How can I (by a tutorial) install MongoDB on my Raspbian installation?

Comment: I don't know an answer to your question but maybe you could describe a little the problems you had with installing MongoDB according to the given guides?

Comment: I will take a wild guess and ask you - did you install nodejs? BTW: Meteor uses MongoDB and according to this [tutorial](http://meteor-universal.tumblr.com) and also my experience you can install MongoDB. But, as gruentee already said - what is the problem?

Comment: Raspbian is a 32-bit OS, and MongoDB has required a 64-bit platform for quite a while now. Once you have a 64-bit OS installed on your Pi, you can cross-compile from source or get binaries from [GIthub](https://github.com/themattman/mongodb-raspberrypi-binaries).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

MongoDB is available in the Rasbian repo, at least for Jessie.

You can install with:

```
apt-get install mongodb
```

Unfortunately, it is only v2.4.10-5 whereas the current version is v3.2 or so I think.

It seems from the issues list that MongoDB has some coding issues that make it difficult to support non x86/amd64 platforms.

Update June 2017

The version on Rasbian is still the same. There is also another package `mongodb-server`. Not clear what the difference is but it is also the same version. Current versions seem to be either 3.2.14 or 3.4.5

Answer (score 3):

Quote from [bug report SERVER-1811](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1811)

> MongoDB is pleased to announce the 64-bit ARM development release for
>   both its Community and Enterprise offerings. This encompasses the core
>   server components including the shell, mongod and mongos processes,
>   and the server tools. ARM support will apply for Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
>   on ARMv8 or newer. Please note that only the WiredTiger storage engine
>   is supported for the core server. MMAPv1 will not be supported on ARM.
>   The community edition of the binaries are now available on our
>   downloads page for the latest 3.3.11 release. For customers requiring
>   comprehensive support, advanced security features, and certifications,
>   the Enterprise Evaluation Edition is available here Official ARM
>   support will arrive with the MongoDB 3.4 GA.

Sadly only Ubuntu 16.04 support on ARM64 (not even deb package, it's a tarball). At least it's the latest release.

[Download Center:](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community)  `https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-arm64-ubuntu1604-3.4.7.tgz`

See [Install MongoDB Community Edition From Tarball](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/) for install instruction.